# Swift to Swift 2 and Cannot Invoke error. What is wrong?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

I am using an [API](http://docs.ithacaradio.apiary.io/#reference/song-information/get-current-song) that provided the following code that is supposed to provide the song currently playing on the radio station.

```
func getSongs() {

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://api.vicradio.org/songs/current")!
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) in

        if error != nil {
            // Handle error...
            return
        }

        println(error)
        println(response)
        println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
    }

    task.resume()

}
```

This code was written for Swift 1 I believe. I'm getting an error that says:

> Cannot invoke "dataTaskWithRequest" with an argument of list type "NSMutableURLRequest, (NSData!, NSURLResponse!, NSError!) -> _ "

I'm rather new to Swift, so maybe someone could explain how I could correct this error?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
(data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!)
```

to:

```
(data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?)
```

Comment: You will then have some new issues, but at least that will get you past the error you asked about.